# MSK How to mandate both SASL & SSL protocols while validating the client to connect msk broker nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

In MSK to communicate with brokers by using TLS(SSL) we have used 9094 port and able to communicate MSK cluster with the required keystore and truststore configurations.

And to communicate with brokers by using SASL_SCRAM we have used 9096 port and able to communicate MSK cluster with username and password configurations.

And now we want to configure both SASL_SSL to authenticate client while connecting  to broker nodes as a mandatory configurations at client side.

NOTE: We are able to configure both SASL_SSL security protocol on 9096 port but the client configuration considered as the TLS configurations are optional because if we remove TLS properties, still it is able to connect broker nodes.

Im testing this connection with kafka console producer like below:

`./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list b-1.xxx:9096,b-2xx:9096 --producer.config ./bin/client_sasl_ssl.properties --topic TestTopicSASLSSL`

File: client_sasl_ssl.properties

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL 
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512 
#ssl.truststore.location=/path/to/kafka.client.truststore.jks 
#ssl.keystore.location=/path/to/kafka.client.keystore.jks 
#ssl.keystore.password=psswd 
#ssl.key.password=psswd
```

Please note that im able to produce data with or without the above commented ssl properties, which seems optional.

Any option to mandate both SASL and TLS auth protocol to restrict client connection.

Comment: What is "it" here? Your client? Maybe MSK Support will be able to help more since SASL_SSL is the correct listener protocol, but it cannot be on the same port as just SASL

Comment: yes "it" means my client app(producer/consumer).

Comment: Sure, but what client language are you using? Can you share your code config?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is commented there. Please [edit] your question and format the command and properties

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I've update my question.

Comment: I suggest contacting Amazon MSK support since the way you've described is how it is documented, and I don't see any way to change it - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/port-info.html